# Which episode is this from where Fear is being bound?

Tags: cube-x-cursed-x-curious

There's a screenshot from *Cube x Cursed x Curious* where Fear is being bound.

[image: Fear's being bound]

Which episode is this from?

Comment: @Alagaros If a reverse image search helps with the identification of the episode, please provide the result as well. As most reverse image searches *do not seem to provide the episode this screen shot is happening in* as requested by the op

Comment: Personally, I can't actually find the answer to this question via reverse image search. However, I recall this being in episode 9. If someone has access to the series and wants to confirm that, it would be easy to answer.

Comment: @Dimitrimx My bad, sorry! I don't think it would be a bad idea to write a meta post about these kind of questions.

Comment: This question is currently being discussed on meta: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/should-we-allow-from-which-episode-is-this-image-questions

Comment: Question has been answered